# In a small device, how to put top div in bottom and bottom div on top with bootstrap4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 float-sm-right">
         <p>some content</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 float-sm-left">
       <img src="" alt=""/>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is what i have tried but not getting any result. please help

Comment: Use [Bootstrap Order Classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#order-classes).

Comment: but why float is not working

Comment: [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) places an element on the left or right side of its container, not on the top or bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example based on your code using [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 order-last order-md-first">
            <p>Some content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 order-first order-md-last">
            An image
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox):

```css
.container-fluid {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col-md-6 {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.order-md-first {
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    order: 2;
}
 
.order-md-last {
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    order: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-md-6 {
        -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
        flex: 0 0 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
  
    .order-md-first {
        -ms-flex-order: 1;
        order: 1;
    }
  
    .order-md-last {
        -ms-flex-order: 2;
        order: 2;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 order-md-first">
            <p>Some content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 order-md-last">
            <p>An image</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```